# declaring variable in class

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5.1

Is it okay to declare the variable any part of your class ?
I have this code, I am using laravel 5.1 framework

In my controller

```
 public function myTest(){

     $i = 0;<--- is it okay to declare if we use oop,or we should put on top and declare private.
     foreach($myarray as $arr){
            // do something
             // do something with $i
      }


   }
```

Comment: That's okay if you intend that to use only inside your function.

Comment: The way you do it is in fact the preferreable way, as $i  is only relevant for that particular foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine.  But your variable scope is limited to that function only. Outside that function you can not use that variable.  As you used it inside loop,  this will work.  And you can make it global variable also.  That will make your work easy.

Comment: Global variables are generally a bad idea - it's too easy to accidentally change the value or use them without thinking in another part of the code.

Comment: It's depend on your requirement.